# Iterate through unknown Json file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I know how to loop through a known Json structure with PHP. The problem at hand is that I need to loop through every Json element of a file and alter its value, save it in the end. And I **do not know** the structure of the file in advance. My code needs to adapt to the contents of the file. 
This Json file will be several levels deep, like below:

```
{
    "Level 1": "Some text here",
        "Level 2": {
            "Level 3": {
                "Level 3_1" : "More text",
                "Level 3_2" : "Another value",
                    "Level 4": {
                        "Level 5": {
                            "Level 5_1": "Something here",
                            "Level 5_2": "Something else here"
                        }
                    }
            }
       }
}
```

The fact that some elements have no text associated with them trips me. 
My code is currently covering whatever many layers of Json content but it's horrible code and I'm sure there's an efficient, smart way of doing this with PHP but I just couldn't find it.

Here's how I currently have it:

```
$file = file_get_contents($myfile);
$json = json_decode($file, true);
foreach($json as $key=>$value) {
  if(is_array($value)) {
    foreach ($value as $Key2=>$value2) {
    //And son on ...
    }
  } else echo $value; 
}
```

So this can get pretty boring and if there's an additional level of depth all of a sudden in the file, my code will not parse every element. How could this possible be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best arms to alter each and every value from each array is use `array_walk_recursive()`. So you can use it the way you want. Here is an example:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "Level 1": "Some text here",
        "Level 2": {
            "Level 3": {
                "Level 3_1" : "More text",
                "Level 3_2" : "Another value",
                    "Level 4": {
                        "Level 5": {
                            "Level 5_1": "Something here",
                            "Level 5_2": "Something else here"
                        }
                    }
            }
       }
}';

$json_array = json_decode($json, true);

array_walk_recursive(
    $json_array,
    function (&$value, $key) {
        // You may put conditions here if you need
        $value = $value . ' New value';

    }
);

var_dump($json_array);
```

Comment: Thank you. The other solutions actually work too but this does exactly what I need with 5 lines of code.

Comment: Why not `$value .= 'New value';`? You may want to read the first User Contributed Note, as well.

Comment: Is there any difference between them except structural?

Comment: What about clean code? It may be preference too! BTW why did you delete you last message.

Comment: I though part was not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this,using Recursion:

```
function echoData($array)
{
  foreach($array as $k=>$v)
  {
    if(is_array($v))
    {
      return echoData($v);
    }
    else {
      echo $v.'-';
    }
  }
}
$array=[
    "Level 1"=> "Some text here",
        "Level 2"=> [
            "Level 3"=> [
                "Level 3_1" => "More text",
                "Level 3_2" => "Another value",
                    "Level 4"=> [
                        "Level 5"=> [
                            "Level 5_1"=> "Something here",
                            "Level 5_2"=> "Something else here"
                        ]
                    ]
            ]
        ]
];
$array= json_decode(json_encode($array), true);

echoData($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a recursive function that keeps digging:

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "Level 1": "Some text here",
  "Level 2": {
    "Level 3": {
      "Level 3_1" : "More text",
      "Level 3_2" : "Another value",
      "Level 4": {
        "Level 5": {
           "Level 5_1": "Something here",
           "Level 5_2": "Something else here"
         }
      }
    }
  }
}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
function changeValsDeep($array, $func){
  $a = [];
  foreach($array as $k => $v){
    if(is_array($v)){
      $a[$k] = changeDeep($v, $func);
    }
    else{
      $a[$k] = $func($k, $v);
    }
  }
  return $a;
}
function changeAll(){
  return 'Why would you want to do this?';
}
function keyBasedChange($key, $val){
  if($key === 'Level 3_2'){
    return 'Oh look, it works!';
  }
  return $val;
}
function valueBasedChange($key, $val){
  if($val === 'More text'){
    return 'You can make the value what you want now!';
  }
  return $val;
}
print_r(changeValsDeep($array, 'changeAll'));
print_r(changeValsDeep($array, 'keyBasedChange'));
print_r(changeValsDeep($array, 'valueBasedChange'));
?>
```